# itext7: Check for visible content in a specific area

Tags: itext

I want to check specific parts of a pdf file for visible content. With the PdfCanvasProcessor and a custom eventlistener it is possible to check for text and images but for other kind of content this does not work. So what would be the best approach to check fot any visible content?

Regards,
Marco

Comment: By *"other kind of content"* you mean vector graphics? Or do you mean annotations? Or both?

Comment: Yes I mean vector graphics and may be all other stuff that can be displayed but may not be catched by the event listener when using PdfCanvasProcessor. I saw that it is possible to add an own operator listener but I think it is very hard to puzzle all commands together to find out if this is a visble part of the area I wish to check

Comment: Ok, I considered your task for a while. First of all, **vector graphic events *can be caught* by the event listener when using `PdfCanvasProcessor`**. I considered creating an example for that here but eventually didn't because this actually is only a minor detail of your task. Also considering your other question it becomes clear that *extracting every single item* drawn in the area of interest is the *easy part* of the task, *finding out whether there is any item visible* after all those items are drawn is the hard one. This effectively requires a rendering functionality ...

Comment: ... This effectively requires a rendering functionality (which you did ask for in your [other recent question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46109077/1729265)). Considering the complexity of PDF this is highly non-trivial. There are pure Java libraries which do allow you to render PDF to image but I'm pretty sure that it is easy to fool them. Thus, unless you restrict the PDFs to process to ones that don't use a number of features (or allow for a certain error rate for your tool), I'm afraid this question (doing it using iText 7) is far too broad for a single answer here on stack overflow.

Comment: If you are interested in code for extracting vector graphic instructions, please say so.