# Itext7: render PDF page to image

Tags: image, pdf, itext, itext7, pdf-conversion

Can I render a PDF Page to a real image object (e.g. BufferedImage) using IText 7?

Comment: That was never supported in iText, not in iText 5, not in iText 7. At iText Group, we aren't interested in this ancient use case.

Comment: Just a quick note that as of this year, iText now has an addon called pdfRender for this exact use case.
(disclaimer: at the time of writing this comment, I am an iText employee)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, consider using GhostScript.

> Ghostscript is a suite of software based on an interpreter for Adobe
>   Systems' PostScript and Portable Document Format (PDF) page
>   description languages. Its main purposes are the rasterization or
>   rendering of such page description language files, for the display or
>   printing of document pages, and the conversion between PostScript and
>   PDF files. -- wikipedia

As Bruno said, iText generally does not go into the rendering domain.

However, keep in mind what kind of a situation you're creating for the people who wish to use this "document" after you're done with it. Text-extraction will no longer work (unless you OCR it), you lose any search functionality or meta-information, etc.

Comment: I won't use this transformation for display to end users. I wanna have a buffered image that I can process internally to find out if specific areas have visible content or not. (Please also see my other post were I try another way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104097/itext7-check-for-visible-content-in-a-specific-area

Comment: That sounds similar to what we do for our internal testing. We run some code to produce documents and then verify them against a pdf to check for structural differences. If there are structural differences, we turn both pdfs into images and compare them visually.

Comment: Would that be adaptable for my problem? And if so how can I do this. It is very hard to understand itext and pdf in such a deep level

Comment: The idea would be to use GhostScript to turn a pdf into an image (or a series of images, one per page), and then you can load those into Java using regular ````Image.IO````